# React doesn't update component after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've some trouble while using React for my first time. I wrote a simple class as follow in my project :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class FigosTest extends React.Component {
  state = {
    provider: 'unknown',
    date: 'sometime'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('x.com/some_api')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.provider);
        console.log(res.data.date);
        this.setState(this.setState(res.data));
        console.log("After");
        console.log(this.state.provider);
        console.log(this.state.date);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return this.provider || 'undefined';
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Result: <FigosTest/>
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want to get and display some data from the API I'm asking. I used to do this a call to this API that will render me an object containing only `provider` and `date` labels.

Let's say I want to display the provider. I see with `console.log` that my component achieve to query the API, and to return my values.

My problem is that the component wouldn't update after this operation.

I tried to callback App.render, to use [schouldComponentUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066833/react-component-not-re-rendering-when-state-changes), and in [others posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628045/change-to-react-state-doesnt-update-display-in-functional-component), I noticed that everybody use `ReactDOM.render()`. What is it ? How to use it ?

Regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469189/state-not-changing-after-calling-this-setstate/53469851#53469851

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues, one or more of which are probably the problem (particularly #4):

1. [State changes are **asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). You won't see the changes to state on `this.state` immediately after calling it. If you need to see the changes, use the callback (the second argument to [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)).
2. `setState` has no return value, so it doesn't make sense to call `setState` with the return value of `setState`. I wouldn't think that was the problem, but this:

   ```
   this.setState(this.setState(res.data));
   ```

   should be

   ```
   this.setState(res.data);
   ```
3. The documentation doesn't say that the `render` method can return `undefined`. So it's not defined (no pun!) if you return `undefined`, as you're doing.
4. In your `render`, you're using `this.provider`. If `provider` is provided by `res.data`, you should be using `this.state.provider`.

You mentioned looking at various other methods (`componentShouldUpdate`, etc.), but there's no need in this case. You're kicking off your async process in the right place (`componentDidMount`), and setting state in response to that completing (which is also correct, though see #1 and #2 above).

Comment: The more impactant was the #4, indeed. For the #3, it was only in textual, so it's only for displaying, not for the `undefined` value. And I correct the #2. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also confirm if your state has updated or not.

```
this.setState(res.data, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see below.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class FigosTest extends React.Component {
  state = {
    provider: 'unknown',
    date: 'sometime'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('x.com/some_api')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.provider);
        console.log(res.data.date);
        this.setState(res.data, () => {
          console.log("After");
          console.log(this.state.provider);
          console.log(this.state.date);
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return this.provider || 'undefined';
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Result: <FigosTest/>
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you changed, and why. Also, this doesn't fix the majority of the problems, and if you use Stack Snippets, the snippet should be *runnable* (this one isn't, it throws a syntax error). Stack Snippets do support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).